# android : navigation drawer and upgrading libraries methodology

Tags: android

Im following headfirst methodology to learn to code in androidstudio.
they provide some code for building a simple navigation drawer app.
in order to be compatible with previous android version, they advise to import :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

but in my last version of android studio this doesnt work : some of them are greyed and alt+enter does not import the correct library when i put the java code provided by my methodology.

so i replaced a few imports with the newer versions. for example :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle ;
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

however, i did not find anything for to import "NavigationView" and com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationV iew is grayed when i try to import it.

So my question is basic: how do i know which lib to import when android studio does not suggest anything with alt+enter and when the libraries have evolved? the question could be asked for many programs i guess ..is there a standard methodology to upgrade the code?

Comment: Welcome! It may help others if you were to include all of the code, not just the imports.  Also include any error messages you're encountering.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to include your dependencies in your build.gradle (app) file.

For example, your NavigationView is a part of Google's Material library. This library does not come included in Android SDK when you create the project and therefore you need to add the library under 'dependencies' in your build.gradle (app) file in order to use it:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'

}
```

This way, upon the build of the project, Gradle will download the library and include it in your project so you can use the Material components. You can usually find the gradle dependency you need to include with a quick Google search.

Another thing to note is that the legacy support libraries have been replaced with AndroidX as you can read here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx

And you can find the full list of AndroidX support libraries in here:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/explorer